# Add a new column from compare result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need add a new column (status) on my main table (Table 1) on my bd Postgres, to do this , I need to compare two columns from table 1 on table 2 , if the two columns exist , I need to copy the status from table 2 to the new column on table 1 , if not exist , e need to fill the status column with 'New'. Do youw know if it´s possible ? how ?

```
    TABLE 1 
HOST        | UUID
HOST - 1    | 3
HOST - 4    | 5
HOST - 3    | 6
HOST - 4    | 9
HOST - 5    | 10
HOST - 6    | 12
HOST - 8    | 2
HOST - 8    | 14

        TABLE 2     
HOST        | UUID  | STATUS
HOST - 4    | 9     | OPEN
HOST - 6    | 12    | ACCEPT
HOST - 8    | 14    | CLOSED

    TABLE 1 (new column status)
HOST        | UUID  | STATUS
HOST - 1    | 3     | NEW
HOST - 4    | 5     | NEW
HOST - 3    | 6     | NEW
HOST - 4    | 9     | OPEN
HOST - 5    | 10    | NEW
HOST - 6    | 12    | ACCEPT
HOST - 8    | 2     | NEW
HOST - 8    | 14    | CLOSED
```

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvYmd.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWkRF.png)

[Table 1 with a new status column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0uow.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do you *need* to add a new column? Why not a `VIEW`?

Comment: There´s no problem to use a view on this case, but I don´t know how can I construct the query to compare. Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a `LEFT` join of `Table1` to `Table2`:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2.status, 'NEW') status
from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2
on t2.uuid = t1.uuid and t2.host = t1.host
```